# How to combine Grafana/Prometheus series after relabeling

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-mimir

I have Prometheus configured to scrape metrics from an ec2 instance. At some point I wrote an extra relabeling rule that populates the new `ec2_vpc_id` value.

```
- job_name: ec2
  scrape_interval: 15s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /metrics

  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_vpc_id]     <-- newly added
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: ec2_vpc_id
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  ec2_sd_configs:
  - endpoint: ""
    region: us-west-1
    port: 1234
```

My graph in Grafana now shows 2 distinct series before and after the relabeling.

```
node_load1{instance="$node",job="$job",ec2_vpc_id=~".*"}
```

The yellow series is my old metric without `ec2_vpc_id`. The green series is the new metric with `ec2_vpc_id`. Both of them are of the same host.

It looks like Grafana automatically separates them intro 2 distinct series. How do I combine them into one?

[image: grafana]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prometheus is the one who makes distinction between this series.

Prometheus considers two timeseries different if they have different label set.

To avoid this distinction you need to use query, that will remove label `ec2_vpc_id` from consideration.

For example, this can be done with

```
sum without(ec2_vpc_id) (node_load1{instance="$node",job="$job"})
```

Comment: Additionally selector `=~".*"` does nothing, so there is no need for it

Comment: I am able to confirm this works now, thank you!